# fill a 2-dimensional JButton Array with different images

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I am working on a small easter egg in my game, [this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOaK6.png). If the player clicks a specific button 5 times, every button that is not black get's a different picture. So far I managed to make it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJiUB.png) where every Button has the same picture.

The code for the image and change every button's image is this:

```java
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("kronk/18.png"));

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { //Goes one time through the complete Array
    for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {

        if(buttons[i][j].getBackground() != Color.black) {
            buttons[i][j].setText("");
            buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        }
    }
}
```

The code so far is hardcoded to always display 18.png

The images are stored in a folder which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aeqB.png), where 1.png goes on Button 1, 2.png goes to 2, etc...

What would be the best way to fill every button with it's corresponding image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { //Goes one time through the complete Array
    for (int j = 0; j < buttons[i].length; j++) {
        if(buttons[i][j].getBackground() != Color.black) {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("kronk/"+(i*5 + j + 1)+".png"));
            buttons[i][j].setText("");
            buttons[i][j].setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        }
    }
}
```

As you have a 5x5 array `i*5 + j` will give you the elemnts count from 0 to 24. But since the enumeration of your pictures starts with one you have to add one at the end `i*5 + j + 1`

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. Have fun coding!